# Error - Grass 7 doesn´t run because isn´t not sucessfully installed

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin, msys

I am having problems to run GRASS7 from the processing tool. Always run the following error that is not corrected instaled. I ve reinstall QGIS several times, even tried different versions,as also tried many solutions present in similar questions in StackExchange as copy msys, etc.., but so far unsucessfully.

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the GRASS7 folder `C:/PROGRA~1` is suggesting a 32-bit installation folder (`Program Files (x86)`)? Your QGIS might be 64-bit version.

Comment: Hi, the QGIS it´s a 64 bit version. I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bits.

Comment: Then you may have another `GRASS 7` under `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1`. Could you set it up as your GRASS7 Folder and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This problem it´s solved. i realize that anti-virus had block grass and several components. So i have unblocked them, and have re-installed QGIS 2.12 first, then QGIS 2.18. Then copy msys as well as grass 6 folders in apps in QGIS 2.12 to apps in QGIS 2.18. And now both run perfect grass 6 in QGIS 2.12 and grass 7 in the QGIS 2.18

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Please accept the answer to mark it solved.